# reading a file upload removes carriage returns

Tags: file, upload

I am uploading a file. When I read it, the content has the carriage returns removed and I have not been able to figure out how to stop that. The carriage returns are critical in that they are used to delineate lines; it has no line feeds.

Is there a way that I can read the uploaded file without it removing the carriage returns?